# Resizeing textarea on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have found the following code for resizing the textareas to extend according to the content.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").on("keyup",function(){
    var h = $(this).height();
    $(this).css("height","0px");
    var sh = $(this).prop("scrollHeight");
    var minh = $(this).css("min-height").replace("px", "");
    $(this).css("height",Math.max(sh,minh)+"px");  
  });
});
```

The code works well, but the textareas extend only after selecting them and making a change.

I would like them to extend on the page load already.... Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $content = $('.content');
    $.each($content, resize);
    $content.on("keyup", resize);

    function resize(){
        var h = $(this).height();
        $(this).css("height","0px");
        var sh = $(this).prop("scrollHeight");
        var minh = $(this).css("min-height").replace("px", "");
        $(this).css("height",Math.max(sh,minh)+"px");  
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much... Your code makes the textarea to expand on load, but it does not expand it when changing the content. If I use both functions (your and my example), it works just great. But should there be a way to do both actions with one function?

Comment: @sasos You're welcome, I updated the code example to what you asked for, try it out. :)

Comment: No problem. :) Could you mark my answer as correct?

Comment: Yes... I did, but I get some message that it will only count my vote when I get 15+ rep points... :/